# mkdir: path should be string not generator

Tags: python, list, operating-system, range

This is my code-

```
import os
os.mkdir(str(i) for i in list(range(1,11)))
```

It gives the error in title. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mkdir` takes as an argument a string. You are passing it a generator expression that will generate successive values '1', '2', ... '10' when you *iterate* it. You need to use a loop to make individual calls passing a single string argument:

```
import os

for i in range(1, 11):
    os.mkdir(str(i))
```

By the way, the expression `list(range(1, 11))` will create a `list` from a `range` object. But if you are going to be using the result in a `for` loop as in the above code, it is wasteful to create the list; just use the `range` object directly.